# Is it possible to enable Unity Web Apps desktop integration with Firefox Web apps downloaded from the Mozilla Marketplace?

Tags: unity, firefox, webapps

The Mozilla Marketplace has opened a few days ago for early adopters, developers, and testers. With a few tricks, it's entirely possible to install Firefox Web Apps (Which are really handy) on Ubuntu. However, using the twitter Web App for instance, doesn't enable the Twitter desktop integration that the user benefits from while visiting Twitter.com in a Firefox tab. Is there a workaround to enable the Web Apps to be integrated into the desktop as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity WebApps are different from the WebApps that are provided by Chrome/Firefox. Though they serve the same purpose in a different way

Unity WebApps are programmed to integrate with Ubuntu application management features like

- Notifications
- Media Menu
- Unity HUD
- Messaging Menu
- Launcher

but where as in Firefox and Chrome the webpage is turned into web app which doesn't provide  much integration with Ubuntu.

To know more about Unity WebApps check [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.04/javascript/index.html)